# Sharepoint Online - List Existing “Send To Connections" in C#

Tags: c#, sharepoint-online, csom

I need to create a C# method that Lists existing  "Send To Conections"  inside a Sharepoint Online Central Administration (https://MYSERVER-admin.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/TA_OfficialFileAdmin.aspx), returning a `List<string>` with connection Display Names.

That's possible?

Example: 
`private List<string> GetSendToConnections(){}`

[Send To Connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aONL3.png)

Comment: This question should be asked at https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/. Also please consider showing your sample implementation of this method